# How to see what port was blocked in iptables log file?

Tags: iptables

I have created few iptables rules and I have tested them. I created `INPUT, OUTPUT` chains using following code:

```
  #!/bin/bash



iptables -F

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -N accept-input

iptables -A accept-input -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT-ACCEPTED "
iptables -A accept-input -j ACCEPT


iptables -N drop-input

iptables -A drop-input -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT-DROPPED "
iptables -A drop-input -j DROP

iptables -N accept-output

iptables -A accept-output -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT-ACCEPTED "
iptables -A accept-output -j ACCEPT

iptables -N drop-output

iptables -A drop-output -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT-DROPPED "
iptables -A drop-output -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -j drop-input
iptables -A OUTPUT -j drop-output
```

and I have added other rules to allow specific ports. I want to see the DROPPED packets. I am using port 9191 for IIS websites. I can't reach websites because it is being blocked.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep DROPPED /var/log/kern.log
```

or

```
dmesg|grep DROPPED
```

Comment: thanks for reply! This works, but is there a way to see what port was blocked? Let say I try to ssh and it gets dropped, so can I see port 22 blocked or dropped?

Comment: kernel: [38753.696042] DROPPED: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=x.x.x.x DST=x.x.x.x LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=42248 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=45146 **DPT=23** WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0